# Bootstrap 4 Popover CSS Not Dynamically Changing

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a dark theme that changes the background color of the whole page. However, this does not change the background color of the popovers I have.

I was wondering if anybody has any ideas? The issues I am having is I change the CSS of the popover but it doesn't update whenever I open the popover.

I've tried just changing the css itself to tomato and it does initialize properly, so I know that popovers can be changed.

Here is the css of the darktheme and popover:

```css
.dark-theme {
            color: #e1e1e1;
            background-color: #333333;
            transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
        }
.popover {
            background-color: tomato;
        }
```

Here is the script the darktheme runs

```
function IsDarkTheme()
{
       darkThemeEnabled = document.body.classList.toggle('dark-theme');
       localStorage.setItem('darkThemeEnabled', darkThemeEnabled);
       $("popover").css({"background-color": "#333333"});
}
```

Here is the jquerythat creates the popover

```
$('#RESET').ready(function () {
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
        placement: 'top',
        html: true,
        title: 'Are you sure? <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</a>',
        content: '<button id="RESETCON" onclick="RESET()" type="button" class="btn btn-danger w-100">Yes, I want to reset everything!</button>'
    });
    $(document).on("click", ".popover .close", function () {
        $(this).parents(".popover").popover('hide');
    });
});
```

Edit: [Here is it currently live](http://borkclicker.com/).

Edit 2: I figured out that the popover does change color IF and ONLY IF it is already opened when I click to change to dark theme. I dont know how to change the color of all popovers even if they are not shown, created, or anything yet.

Comment: Do you have the page live somewhere or can you create a codepen to reproduce the problem?

Comment: @Mindless here is it currently live http://forodin.heliohost.org:8080/Example/

Comment: where is the popover, i see a tooltip only

Comment: Just added it in an edit, the popover is created in jquery by clicking the buttons. @Mindless

Comment: I can see on the reset button, the background color of the popover is changing when you select dark theme, but not the button inside the popover, 1. add code to change the color of the button on dark theme select 2. try clear your cache

Comment: @Mindless I've tried clearing my cache and it still does not work for me. The reset button should also force clear everything and hard reload aswell. What web browser are you on? I want the button to remain the same color, I just want everything else to change.

Comment: Im so confused, you want the popover to remain the same color or change with the theme? Sorry I don't understand what you want now.

Comment: I want the popover to change with the theme to enable the user to read the text @Mindless

Comment: I'm using chrome, and the background color changes fine when you change to the code in the answer, and I see the color of the popover background change on the live website before.

Comment: If the code isn't working properly, there must be something else forcing the color of the popover, I couldn't help because i'm not sure exactly what you want to achieve, a few screenshots with explanation might help.

Comment: I'm just trying to change the background color of the popover box to match the current background when on dark theme and then to reverse when dark theme is off. (This includes the title region, the content itself, and the little arrow) @Mindless

Edit: The issue is it appears to sometimes work for me (like every dozen tries) and it only does it to one of the popovers

Comment: ok, the issue isn't on the jquery part, but the logic in which you change your color of the popover, I'm not going to debug everything on your code but this should be your logic: 1. On theme change SELECT, change the color of the popover to dark(which you are currently doing) 2. On theme change DESELECT, change the color of the popover to default. Consider using checkbox .change function, you are only changing the color to dark but there is no way to change it back at the moment.

Comment: The thing is the popover isn't even changing colors for me. It has once even though i've tried and tested over a dozen times. And even then, it only changed one of the popovers. @Mindless So i can't even begin to figure out the checkbox issue when the popover doesn't change

Comment: @Mindless I just added an edit that describes what causes it to work. I discovered the color only changes if the popover is open when you click to change to dark theme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just created a codepen https://codepen.io/anon/pen/Jqyvxa

This will fix your issue with popover not registering css changed because it's hidden, the trick is to toggle the popover before the css change and then hide it.

```
//init popover
$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();

//on checkbox change
$('#ChangeTheme').change(function() {
  //if checked
  if(this.checked) {
    console.log("Theme changed dark");

    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover('show');

    $(".popover").css("background", "black");

    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover('hide');
  }
  //if not checked
  else {
    console.log("Theme changed white");

    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover('show');

    $(".popover").css("background", "white");

    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover('hide');
  }
});
```

Or you can check for popover shown event and then on shown event, check if the checkbox is checked or not and then change the background accordingly

```
//init popover
$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();

//popover shown event
$('[data-toggle="popover"]').on('shown.bs.popover', function () {
  console.log("Popover show event")

  if($("#ChangeTheme").is(":checked")) {
    console.log("Theme changed dark");
    $(".popover").css("background", "black");
  }
  else
  {
    console.log("Theme changed white");
    $(".popover").css("background", "white");
  }
})
```

Just beware that because the background is changing on popover shown, it won't change when you toggle the checkbox if the popover is already open.

Answer (score 2):

This line is incorrect:

```
$("popover").css({"background-color": "#333333"});
```

You are selecting `<popover>` elements, which probably do not exist in your document.
Try the class selector:

```
$(".popover").css({"background-color": "#333333"});
```

Comment: I just tried that and it didn't do anything, here is it currently live. http://forodin.heliohost.org:8080/Example/

Comment: @ItsOYo the above line of code appears to work (paste into console and check the popover element), so the issue may be somewhere else in your code. Perhaps post your event setter/execution for troubleshooting?

Comment: @Frish just posted my jquery code that initializes the popover upon a button click, could that be the cause?

Comment: I just added an edit that describes what causes it to work. I discovered the color only changes if the popover is open when you click to change to dark theme. How can I make it so it changes all popovers even if it's hidden, not created, or etc?